# Access a vector<object> from another class' method

Tags: c++, oop

I have a Player class and a Game class.

My Game.cpp has has a `setPlayers` method. It compiles without an error but when I use it in my main, it doesn't work and gives me segmentation fault instead. Is it even possible to access a vector of another object from another object's method?
main.cpp

```
#include "player.h"
#include "game.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    Game one;
    std::cout << "Position names: \n";
    std::cout << "Factory:1, ";
    std::cout << "Distributor:2, ";

    bool player_check[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    int role_choice;
    int player_count;

    while(1){
      Player p;
      jump_to_choice:
        std::cout << "Enter your position: ";
        std::cin >> role_choice;
        p.setRole(role_choice);
        if(player_check[p.getRole()-1] == 0){
          std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
          //Adding a player to the Player* vector defined in game.h (players)
          one.setPlayers(&p, p.getRole()-1);
          player_check[p.getRole()-1] = 1;
          player_count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Player.h:

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include "iostream"

class Game;

class Player {

private:
    int role;
    Game* game;
public:

    void setRole(int role);

    int getRole();
};

#endif
```

Player.cpp

```
int Player::getRole() {
    return this->role;
}
void Player::setRole(int newRole) {
    std::cout << "setting role" << std::endl;
    this->role = role;
}
```

Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "shipment.h"
#include "order.h"
#include "player.h"

class Game
{

private:
  int gId;
  std::vector<Player*> players;
public:
  std::vector<Player*> getPlayers();
  void setPlayers(Player*, int);
};
#endif
```

Game.cpp

```
void Game::setPlayers(Player* player_arg, int p_position){
  players[p_position] = player_arg;
}
```

Comment: Remember that vectors start out *empty*. Any indexing in an empty vector will be out of bounds and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. passing `&p` to `setPlayers` looks wrong but I dont think it is the cause of your current problem

Comment: Don't confuse *header files* with *classes,* *classes* with *objects* or *run-time* errors with *compile-time* errors.

Comment: @idclev463035818 Could you see the updated qs?

Comment: @Beta could you see the updated qs?

Comment: @FSJ yes, updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems in the code you posted.

First, vectors start with zero size unless you construct one with non-zero size. You create a vector with no elements and then here

```
void Game::setPlayers(Player* player_arg, int p_position){
  players[p_position] = player_arg;
}
```

you use `operator[]` to access elements. Noticed something? You cannot acces an element in an empty vector. Use `push_back` to add an element at the back. Actually if you want to have players at certain positions, then a `std::unordered_map` would be easier, they can be used as "sparse" arrays, ie you could add a `Player` at `p_position = 12` even if this is the first player you add.

Secondly,

```
one.setPlayers(&p, p.getRole()-1);
```

the pointer `&p` has always the same value. It is the adress of the local object `Player p;`. That object gets destroyed when you leave the scope and all pointers in the vector become dangling pointers. It is a common mistake to store pointers in containers when you actually want a container of objects. Use a `std::vector<Player>` instead.

Comment: I'm trying to use ```std::unordered_map<int, <Player*>> playersMap;``` but it keeps giving me ```expected an identifier``` on Player